# Model associations for 'Availability' in canonical Patient / Physician / Appointment schema?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I'm following a minimal [tutorial](http://davidpots.com/rails/tutorial/development/2013/04/02/rails-basics-has-many-through.html), and to summarise, here are the three models:

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end
```

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, :through => :appointments
end
```

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, :through => :appointments
end
```

This is all good so far. Now I try to add a fourth model `Availability` that stores records of the physician's available time slots (so the physician can determine when they are/aren't available, and so the patients won't be shows times that aren't available)

Trouble is, I can't work out the associations. i.e. what needs to change in the above.

#### My (probably wrong) attempt:

- Physician has_many availabilities
- New Availability model that belongs_to physician

But I am kinda guessing:

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end
```

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, :through => :appointments
  has_many :availabilities
end
```

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, :through => :appointments
end
```

```
class Availability < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
end
`
```

Comment: As i understand from your schema. Physician can have free or busy hours in a day and for the specific hour of a day more than one Physician may be available . If so you should define a many-to-many relation between Physician and Availability.

Comment: @MehmetAdilİstikbal that's correct. But also a Patient will first select a Physician and only then see their available times (they won't select a time first, then which Physician is available). Do you know exactly what needs to change in the above code?

Comment: @MehmetAdilİstikbal I was planning each Availability could have any start_time and end_time that the physician enters. And the view will only show possible appointments that are within those times entered by the physician. So to answer your question specially, the physician could enter absolutely any start_time and any end_time, and have as many Availabilities as they wanted, and they can maintain up to a month in advance

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @CaTs first time doing this kinda thing and literally don’t know what code to write. Googling many to many now but still not quite sure. If you know what the four models should look like id appreciate the tip!

Comment: @stevec Well the problem statement is vague but looking at purely the relations, appointment should not be getting to physician through availability since it has no relation to availability.

Comment: @CaTs thanks! great observation. I removed that from my attempt above

Comment: @CaTs please let me know if I can expain something better? The goal is a minimal booking app that lets a patient book a physician, and lets the physician set their availability. I am not really sure of what I am doing, but getting the models right is my first step. If you have ideas they are appreciated

Comment: @stevec I would clarify what is going wrong with your current attempt. Is it giving a particular error when you try to do something?

Comment: @CaTs I think with your suggestion it works! I honestly had no idea, so I might have been closer than I thought initially. Really appreciate the help

Comment: @CaTs I am fleshing out the model validations and the rest of the columns in the tables, so I'll know soon if it works as I hoped. I will update either way